# Calculation of Fama-French risk factors

Tags: finance, portfolio-management, returns, factor-models, fama-french

Background:
I am conducting some research on equity returns across Denmark, Finland, Norway and Sweden. The analysis is seen from a Danish investor’s point of view, and therefore I have currency adjusted all return data into DKK.

All data is retreived from Thomson Reuters Eikon.

Question:
Right now I am trying to calculate the Fama-French (1993) three factor model (mkt, smb and hml). Should I also currency adjust the data I use as input for computing the SMB and HML factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

[Size, value, and momentum in international stock returns](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.409.2911%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ved=2ahUKEwjV5Jr26ZrzAhX1g_0HHXtyCtkQFnoECBMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2Mn3sMX6jwBCvaMecdfXv5&cshid=1632597305065) by Fama French states:

> SMB is the equal-weight average of the returns on the three small stock portfolios for the region minus the average of
> the returns on the three big stock portfolios.

HML is the difference between the returns on diversified portfolios of high book-to-market (value) stocks and
low book-to-market (growth) stocks.

The description of table 1 explains that:

> All returns are in U.S. dollars.

Comment: thanks a lot!! I wonder if you know if there is any MATLAB or Python code on the computation of these factors published at this forum? I am new at stackexchange and still have some difficulties using the search function.

Comment: Do you mean computing HML or SMB with python code? If so, if you Google this, you will find numerous useful results like [this one](https://github.com/RobertYip/Python-Fama-French-Quant-model). It's really just sorting returns in the dataframe though.